# use whois command to get information about ADMINISTRATIVE CONTACT

Tags: networking

When searching whois on cisco.com through a website [whois.com](https://www.whois.com/whois/cisco.com), I get information on ADMINISTRATIVE CONTACT (infosec@cisco.com).  However, when running command `whois cisco.com`, it doesn't give the information on ADMINISTRATIVE CONTACT.

Wonder how to use `whois` command or something similar to get the info.

I tried many command line switches for whois (running on ubuntu 14.04) like `whois --verbose cisco.com`, but none helped.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: using the whois server `geektools.com`:

```
$ whois -h geektools.com cisco.com 
GeekTools Whois Proxy v5.0.6 Ready.
Checking access for 70.118.89.36... ok.

Checking server [whois.crsnic.net]

Checking server [whois.corporatedomains.com]
Results:

Domain Name: cisco.com
Registry Domain ID: 4987030_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
Registrar URL: www.cscprotectsbrands.com
Updated Date: 2017-05-11T05:15:34Z
Creation Date: 1987-05-14T04:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2018-05-15T04:00:00Z
Registrar: CSC CORPORATE DOMAINS, INC.
Registrar IANA ID: 299
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@cscglobal.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8887802723
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Info Sec
Registrant Organization: Cisco Technology Inc.
Registrant Street: 170 West Tasman Drive
Registrant City: San Jose
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Postal Code: 95134
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.4085273842
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: +1.4085264575
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: infosec@cisco.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Info Sec
Admin Organization: Cisco Technology Inc.
Admin Street: 170 West Tasman Drive
Admin City: San Jose
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Postal Code: 95134
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.4085273842
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: +1.4085264575
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: infosec@cisco.com
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: Network Services
Tech Organization: Cisco Technology Inc.
Tech Street: 170 W. Tasman Drive
Tech City: San Jose
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Postal Code: 95134
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.4085279223
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: +1.4085267373
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: dns-info@CISCO.COM
Name Server: ns2.cisco.com
Name Server: ns1.cisco.com
Name Server: ns3.cisco.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
....
```

Thanks to the author who pointed it out [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/253451/whois-command-not-returning-useful-information/253566#253566).